# How do I remove Wondershare Video Converter from MacBook Air Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, applications

I have changed my mind about this app but when I try to remove it by dragging it to the trash and then try to empty the trash I get a message that the trash can not be emptied because the program is running. How do I stop it running so I can trash it?

Answer (score 1):

- Reboot, then move it to Trash.
- Open Activity Monitor, find it in the list, then quit it, and drag it to Trash.

Answer (score 0):

Try the free app AppCleaner which will delete it and and all of its associated files.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I found online about how to remove Wondershare from Mac.

- Click Start menu and move your mouse to All Programs.
- Find Wondershare Video Converter for Mac 2.0.0 folder and click on its Uninstaller.
- Follow its uninstaller and uninstall the program.

To run its uninstaller, you can also

- Go to the folder where the program is installed.
- Locate its uninstaller usually named as unins000.exe or uninstall.exe
- Double click on its uninstaller and follow it to uninstall the program.

Comment: How do you run an `.exe` on a Mac?